# Defining case classes when the supervisor and child actor share same messages

Tags: scala, akka

The best practice is that the messages that are handled by an actor should be defined in the companion object of the actor. Where should they be defined if the messages are common to both supervisor and child actor? Should they be defined in the companion object of both actors? Also, where should the case classes be if they are shared across other actors?

Answer (score 1):

For cases when Messages are shared between multiple actors I use protocol layer abstraction:

```
public abstract class ActorProcessingProtocol {

            private ActorProcessingProtocol () {
            }

            public static class ActionStart implements Serializable {}
            public static class ActionDone implements Serializable {}
            ...
}
```

This was inspired by some akka scala example, but applied in java.